# iBeacons in iOS - no callbacks from actual BLE device but didRangeBeacons gets called when another iOS device is used as broadcaster

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am using Sensor Tag as a broadcaster Bluetooth low energy device with which I am unable to identify beacons array mentioned in method **didRangeBeacons** returning 0 count on Receiver application iOS Device. As there are not such devices observed in this array, not able to find out Proximity UUID, major and minor values.

On the other hand, when I used other iOS device as a broadcaster and then tried to print logs in method **didRangeBeacons** its giving us array with beacons which allows me to fetch the proximity UUID, major & minor values.

I don't doubt anything is wrong in a code as I tested with 2 ios devices with broadcaster application installed with 2 different UUIDs and same are giving signals in Receiver application when same UUIDs are registered for receiving signals from any BLE broadcasters.

I doubt -

1. Either external BLE device (Sensor tag from Texas Instrument) not creating the region in which we can receive signals.
2. We might have to do some extra settings in .plist file or in Xcode to receive signals from any other BLE device other that iOS device as broadcaster.
3. UUID being registered for both broadcaster & Receiver might not be matching to get the signals in **didRangeBeacons**.

Has someone faced this problem ever? Please suggest.

Code:

```
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     _locationManager.delegate = self; 
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
     _beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 minor:1 identifier:identifier];
     self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
 self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
 self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES; 
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:_beaconRegion]; 
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_beaconRegion];`
```

Comment: Put you code where you start monitoring or startRanging your beacons

Comment: Just a moment. adding the code.

Comment: `_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`
 _locationManager.delegate = self;

 NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];

 _beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 minor:1 identifier:identifier];

 self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
 self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
 self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

 [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:_beaconRegion];
 [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_beaconRegion];`

Comment: please click the "edit" button below the tags on your question and add the code there

Comment: Have you set major 1 and minor 1 on your SensorTag?  Does `uuidString` match the uuid on your SensorTag?

Comment: @Paulw11: Yes, UUID string matches with the one which was there for for sensor tag

Comment: And you have configured major 1 and minor 1 on your SensorTag?

Comment: I didn't do this for sensor tag. I did this for another iPad devices as a broadcaster. There, I was getting proximity id, major and minor values. but for Sensor tag, I directly start using that as it is. Do we have to do any setup that moment for sensor tag to get that identified in **didRangeBeacons**?

Comment: For the SensorTag you need to load the iBeacon firmware and then use the iOS app to set a major and minor. You can specify major and minor 0 in your region to just match on UUID but if you specify a non-zero value then that value must match

Comment: As of now, I don't need any thing to be done for major and minor values. I just need to get UUID.

code:

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region'

Comment: at least I should get the array mentioned in above method. so that I should get UUID and no major and minor values.

Is that possible, or is it mandatory to use that BLE device with major and minor values also?

Comment: If you specify 0 for major and minor then it will return all beacons that match the UUID only.  Have you loaded the iBeacon firmware onto the SensorTag?  A SensorTag is not an iBeacon "out of the box" - http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_with_iBeacon

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 for such quick response.

I didn't load anything on Sensor Tag. I started using that as is provided by TI. I will check the link you mentioned here and try to setup if any required steps to use sensor tag as a iBeacon advertiser device.

Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Paulw11: When I received a response from TI team about Sensor Tag, they said, MFi program is required to use sensor tag as a iBeacon device.Similar line is mentioned in a link you provided in below text -

Is it required before we proceed. Earlier, I did update Sensor Tag firmware with version 1.5.

"To use iBeacon on the SensorTag, Apple require you to be an iBeacon licensee. To apply for an iBeacon licensee go to the Apple MFI program and fill in the application form. After you are approved, you can request access to the iBeacon software for SensorTag at the SensorTag SW page"

Comment: All I know is what is written on their page - they require an MFi license in order to receive the firmware.

Comment: Yes. That's what my observation also. Just a last question on this discussion if you know it would be great help for me.

Do you know any other BLE providers who all don't need MFi program or we can directly use that as a advertiser device. Let me know if you know so that I can order that and get it verified.

Comment: There are lots of iBeacon devices available.  I have used the LightBlue Bean from Punchthrough Design, but there are also Estimote, Kontact.io and Radius Networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TI SensorTag does not operate as an iBeacon "Out of the box". You need to install the [iBeacon specific firmware from TI](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_with_iBeacon).  TI does not not make this firmware available unless you have signed an iBeacon license agreement with Apple.

I would suggest you look at other beacon hardware if you don't want to go through the Apple License process.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanations are:

1. Your SensorTag is not transmitting the same UUID/major/minor as your configured CLBeaconRegion in your code above.
2. Your SensorTag is not transmitting a well formed beacon advertisement at all.

It is very hard to troubleshoot this with only an iOS device, because CoreLocation stubbornly refuses to tell you anything at all unless everything matches perfectly including the identifiers.

If you have access to an Android 4.3+ device or a OSX machine, you can use these to check the SensorTag advertisement to see if it is sending out the right thing.  On OSX, you can try [ScanBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/scanbeacon/), which dislays all beacon advertisements regardless of identifiers.  On Android, you can use [Bluetooth LE Scanner.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.alt236.btlescan)

If you do not have any such tools to check your transmission, then you should simply double and triple check its configuration until you are certain it is broadcasting with the right identifiers.

**EDIT:** The output of BLE Scanner should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply David. I did check the Bluetooth LE Scanner which returns me some values about GAP, GATT, Device Information and rest all the other listing has Unknown service.

I can see UUID at many places in GAT, GATT. But which would be the ID which I have to use while monitoring. Also where are those major and minor values found which Sensor Tag is broadcasting by default.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you see on the Bluetooth LE scanner?

Comment: Thanks David. I did observe in "Bluetooth LE Scanner" android app that TI Sensor tag doesn't show UUID, major and minor values for Sensor tag as broadcaster. On the other hand, when I checked other iOS devices as broadcaster, I could see those values and that would be the reason why I am getting signals from other iOS deice.

Comment: This says to me that your SensorTag is not configured to send I beacon advertisents.  You need to flash it with the proper firmware.